# Replacement digits in file

Tags: bash, sed, scripting

I have a file with rows which contain timestamps, here is an example:

```
Event   IND200G5200Z5        20151104-030035        20151104-030000+0300    C      5280    10      20151104-025958+0300    OCP      5281    7
Event   IND207X3200Z5        20151104-065436        20151104-030003+0300    UOF      5280    9       20151104-025958+0300    OCP      5281    7
```

I want to delete last 2 digits in the third column to get this:

```
Event   IND200G5200Z5        20151104-0300        20151104-030000+0300    C      5280    10      20151104-025958+0300    OCP      5281    7
Event   IND207X3200Z5        20151104-0654        20151104-030003+0300    UOF      5280    9       20151104-025958+0300    OCP      5281    7
```

There are a lot of lines with different timestamps and I need to delete only 2 last. I don't want to use awk, I need to save changes in same file. I have tried something like this:

```
sed -i 's/d{8}[-]d{6}/d{8}[-]d{4}/'
sed -i 's/\-[0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/'
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: What does using awk or not using awk have to do with saving changes in the same file? Even if you use `sed -i` (a non-POSIX-compliant, non-portable option), it's still going to be writing to a temporary file and renaming over the original, so it's not like you're reducing filesystem IO over doing it that way yourself.

Comment: Please correct me if I misunderstanding something but with awk I need to redirect the output to another file (awk "expression" $file1 > file2) while with using sed it becomes more simply.

Comment: If you have moreutils installed: `awk "expression" "$file1" | sponge "$file1"`. And the `sed -i` version isn't portable -- POSIX sed doesn't support it at all, and GNU sed and OS X sed have variants whose usage is incompatible from each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/-\([0-9]\{4\}\)[0-9]\{2\}/\-\1/' file
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, except the "g" flag in the end of command. Thanks!

Comment: yeah! "g" is not need

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ri 's/(\S+)\S\S/\1/3' file
```

Looking at the data as a whole, this removes the last two non-space characters of the third set of non-space characters.